# Unanticipated behavior using rspec 'expect' shorthand

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I'm seeing different behavior between the two `expect` syntax formats in Rspec:

> `expect(subject).to ...`
>
> versus
>
> `it { is_expected.to ... }`

This works...

```
describe ApplicationController
  controller do
    def index() render nothing: true end
  end

  before { get :index }

  describe "success flash message" do
    subject { flash[:success] }
    it "should be nil" do
      expect(subject).to be_nil
    end
  end
end
```

However this does not...

```
describe ApplicationController
  controller do
    def index() render nothing: true end
  end

  before { get :index }

  describe "success flash message" do
    subject { flash[:success] }
    it { is_expected.to be_nil }
  end
end
```

The error I am getting:

```
1) ApplicationController handling flash messages
   Failure/Error: it { is_expected.to be_nil }
   NameError:
     undefined local variable or method `is_expected' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0x00>
   # ./spec/some/file.rb:123:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

What gives?

- rails (4.0.2)
- rspec-rails (2.14.1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`is_expected` will be introduced in RSpec 3.0.0.beta2. It's only available from github master at this point.

Comment: Duh. Didn't even look at the documentation version on relish. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you do this:

```
subject { flash }
its([:success]) { should be_nil }
```

[its the current recommended way](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/docs/subject/attribute-of-subject)

Comment: Excellent suggestion! Will do this whilst awaiting 3.0 release.

Comment: @fkoehl Note that `its` will be factored out into a separate `rspec-its` gem as of 3.0. In general, you might want to switch to 2.99 in order to get ready for 3.0.

Comment: Yeah I found Myron's [explanation for the removal of `its`](https://gist.github.com/myronmarston/4503509) whilst getting myself up to speed on Rspec. I consequently sidestepped this solution give that, plus its use of the [deprecated `should` syntax](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/blob/master/Should.md)